# read a list from file

Tags: json, list, python-2.7

My file contains this format [{"a":1, "c":4},{"b":2, "d":5}] and I want to read this file into a list in python. The list items should be {"a":1, "c":4} and {"b":2, "d":5}. I tried to read into a string and then typecasting into a list but that is not helping. It is reading character by character.

Answer (score 2):

You can "convert" a string that contains a list to an actual list like this

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[{"a":1, "c":4},{"b":2, "d":5}]')
[{'a': 1, 'c': 4}, {'b': 2, 'd': 5}]
```

You can of course sub out the literal string for the data you read from file

Answer (score 0):

Another, more dirty option is this (it will produce list of strings):

```
a = str('[{"a":1, "c":4},{"b":2, "d":5}]')
b = list()

for i in a.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(sep='},'):
    b.append(i+'}')

b[len(b)-1] = b[len(b)-1].replace('}}','}')

for i in b:
    i


'{"a":1, "c":4}'
'{"b":2, "d":5}'
```

Since ast proposed by Tim earlier will go deaper than first level, it will actually convert underlying string into dictionary. So instead of list of strings you will get list of dictionaries. I am not sure if that's what you want to get.

Comment: `it will actually convert underlying string into dictionary. So instead of list of strings you will get list of dictionaries. I am not sure if that's what you want to get.` I think it is, he said `The list items should be {"a":1, "c":4} and {"b":2, "d":5}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the json module to load json data. Since the json data is a list, it will be converted to a list in python when you call `json.load`:

```
import json

with open(path_to_jsonfile, 'r') as jsonfile:
    jsonlist = json.load(jsonfile)
for listitem in jsonlist:
    print listitem
```

The result should be:

```
{u'a': 1, u'c': 4}
{u'b': 2, u'd': 5}
```

If you're not trying to read the entire file in, and you are just extracting a string from it, and trying to turn that into a list, use the `json.loads` method instead. `json.load` reads a file, `json.loads` reads a string.

Comment: I'm getting an error as "No json object Decoded". I had already tried to load json, but somehow its not working.

Comment: In that case, you need to update the question with exactly what your input is, and the exact code you're using. You've posted valid json in the question, and the code I've posted works correctly.